# How to understand a constant potential in the nearly free electron model?

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

In the nearly free electron model, we assume that the potential is weak.

Now, in a book by Rudolf Gross and Achim Marx, it states:

[image]

I know that the text is in German, but bear with me: The relevant passage is that we assume a "constant potential $V_0$". Two pages later, they have the following diagram:

What really confuses me is the following: The potential they draw is NOT constant!?
But I cannot imagine that this is a printing error, so it seems that I am misunderstanding something

[image]

Comment: Well, yes, the point of the free-electron approximation is to ignore (completely) electron-ion interactions (except perhaps invoked as one of the possible scattering mechanisms). The independent-electron approximation then ignores electron-electron interactions. One thing to note in your 8.7(c) picture is that those deep potential wells are only located very close to the core of the ions. But, yes, the figure appears to be somewhat out of step with what you state the text is doing.

Comment: Please note that here, we are looking at the **nearly** free electron model, not the free electron model! IMHO, this makes a huge difference.

Comment: Well, yes, because then your figure 8.7 makes absolutely no sense whatsoever - the nearly-free electron model is used near zone edges in k-space to get level splitting.